# Using keyword arguments in __getitem__ method in Python

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I want to define a class Foo whose objects can be used like, `foo[1, a=2]`.

I tried to achieve this by decorating the `__getitem__` method of
Foo but with no success. Below is the example code.

```
def decorator(func):
    def func_(*args, **kewargs):
        if 'a' in kewargs:
            args = list(args) + [kewargs['a']]
            return func(*args)
        else:
            return func(*args)
    return func_

class Foo(object):
    @decorator
    def __getitem__(self, *items):
        return items
foo = Foo()

>>> foo.__getitem__(2, a=10)
(2, 10)
>>> foo[2, a=10]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So `foo[...]` is not equivalent to `foo.__getitem__(...)`, something 
behind the scene is done for the former. My question is what exactly and how
can I make `foo[2, a=10]` to work, if at all.

Comment: What would you like `foo[2, a=10]` to *do*, exactly? We can tell you that that syntax will never work, but without knowing the goal we can't suggest anything that would. Note that `__getitem__` **always** (I think...) gets two arguments: `self`, and the contents of the square brackets used on invocation.

Comment: Then that cannot be done, you can't have keyword arguments in a subscription

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I want to make calling  foo.[...] more convenient by allowing keyword args.

Comment: ...my comment above stands

Answer (score 6):

Python allows implicit tuple creation (without  parentheses):

```
In [2]: tup = 1, 2, 3

In [3]: tup
Out[3]: (1, 2, 3)
```

And it works the same inside square brackets:

```
In [4]: d = {(1, 2, 3): 4}

In [5]: d[1, 2, 3]
Out[5]: 4
```

But `(2, a=10)` is not a valid tuple literal:

```
In [6]: (2, a=10)
  File "<ipython-input-1-7dc03602f595>", line 1
    (2, a=10)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Simply put, you can't make `foo[2, a=10]` to work, because it's a syntax error no matter how you tweak your `__getitem__` implementation.

I'd probably define an ordinary method e.g. `get` and use it like `Foo.get(2, a=10)`.

Comment: I would like to intercept '[]' before it converts it's argument to tuple, this is what I was trying to do with the decorator but without success.

Comment: @Tima as I said, decorator (or anything, really) won't help you to avoid the syntax error. Your code does not even have a chance to be executed.

Answer (score 4):

## This is proposed for python 3.6

Using keyword arguments for indexing is currently a syntax error.

However, PEP472 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0472/) proposes this addition to the python syntax.

### Workarounds

The PEP also shows workarounds that are currently valid:

`foo[2, "a":10]` or `foo[2, {"a":10}]`

Comment: That first workaround `foo[2, "a":10]` is considered esotheric by the PEP though. It makes use of a slice object instead of a dictionary (like asking the range between `"a"` and `10` in this case). It can be quite obscure to parse slice objects into dicts, and you will probably lose support for other usage of slice objects this way.

`foo[2, {"a": 10}]` is probably the option that's closest to what the OP wants.